# If "aaa=1", "aab=2" (to max "zzz=??"), how to convert string value to number?

Tags: excel, string, numbers, formula, converters

In this sequence:

```
aaa = 1
aab = 2
aac = 3
aad = 4
aae = 5
...
```

what is the easiest way to convert any other string in the sequence (up to max `zzz`) to a number, say `aem`, or `svg` as random examples?

Is there a spreadsheet formula to do this?

Comment: This is just base 26 with `a` as 0 and with 1 added to every number after converting it from base 26 to the target. Each letter is a digit. `a=0` through `z=25`. From right to left, multiply the first digit by 1, the next by 26, the next by 26*26, etc. and add them up. I don't speak spreadsheet (aren't we supposed to be *programmers* here?)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley : "This is just base 26..." Ha - thus my comment about numeracy in the last paragraph. As for "aren't we supposed to be programmers here?", well some are, and some are people in search of help that programmers might give. I'm the latter. ;) Will see if I can apply your advice in conjunction with answer below. Thanks!

Comment: P.s. about "speaking spreadsheet": the tag "excel" has 1.9K followers, and tags ~26K questions, so there must be a few of them around, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which language do you use. Because you mentioned spreadsheet I assume that it's something like Excel. In Excel the formula should look like this:

```
=(CODE(TEXT)-97)*26*26+
 (CODE(RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT,2),1))-97)*26+
 (CODE(RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT,3),1))-97) +
 1
```

The first line is responsible for the first letter, the second for the second letter and the third for the last letter. In the last line there is +1 because the result would be computed from 0 not 1.

Comment: That's it! Modified slightly for use with LibreOffice Calc, this works beautifully for me: `=((CODE(LEFT(A1))-97)*26*26)+((CODE(MID(A1,2,1))-97)*26)+((CODE(RIGHT(A1))-97)+1` where A1 is the cell with the "aaa" type string. Thanks @gawi!